# Are CSS, JavaScript and jQuery supported in Windows Phone 7 & 7.5 app development?

Tags: css, xaml, windows-phone-7

Are the following things are supported in windows phone 7 / can we make use of these in windows phone 7 application development ?

1. Is CSS supported ?
2. JavaScript supported ?
3. jQuery supported ?

If so please let me know the resources for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser that WP7 uses is based on the same code-base as the desktop IE9. So, yes CSS is supported, with the following CSS3 features:

- CSS 2.1 compliance
- CSS3 2D Transforms
- CSS3 Backgrounds & Borders
- CSS3 Color
- CSS3 Media Queries
- CSS3 Namespaces
- CSS3 Values and Units
- CSS3 Selectors

(From the [Windows Phone Team Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/09/22/ie9-mobile-developer-overview.aspx))

JavaScript and jQuery are both fully supported. As a result it is possible to write HTML-based applications for WP7 as I demonstrated with a [PhoneGap based application which I wrote](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/property-finder-the-first-html5-based-windows-phone-7-application/).

Answer (score 1):

the first browser-version of windows phone 7 was based on IE7 and failed hard at the [Acid3-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid3), so support for css/javascript was there, but very bad.

with Windows Phone 7 Mango there was a browser-update wich changed the browser to IE9 and got 100% at the test - this means there's a pretty good support for javascript and css. at least [jQuery mobile also works](http://wmpoweruser.com/developers-jquery-mobile-now-supports-windows-phone-7/), but i don't know about "normal" jQuery.